# Extending JXDatePicker for Time JComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, actionlistener, swingx

So I'm trying to extend the JXDatePicker to include a Time element.  I have replaced the link panel at the bottom of the JXDatePicker pane with a couple of labels and a couple of drop down boxes (JComboBox), one for hour and one for minute.  However, I can't seem to select anything from either box before the click listener closes the pane as if I have made a date selection.  I don't want to completely override this listener, as I want to keep it closing when I pick a date, but I want to be able to populate the combo boxes before I do.

Does anyone know how I can stop this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: swing doesn't support a popup-in-a-popup ("es kann nur einen geben" :-) If you really want that, you'd need a custom window and handle its positioning/opening/closing logic yourself.

Comment: Ah, that is a damn shame.  Thanks for your answer kleopatra.

Comment: Decided to use JSpinners instead of JComboBoxes.